# Is there a rule for integrating $f(x) f(f(x))$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am looking through rules/tricks for integration, and there are a lot... but I can't seem to find one specifically applicable to the general form
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,f(f(x)) \,\mathrm dx$$

Is there a nice rule or trick that would generally apply in this situation?

Comment: ,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Integration

Comment: How did this come up? I am guessing that $f(x) = e^x$, in which case you are generalizing incorrectly; recall that $f(x) = f'(x)$ in this case...

Comment: @Qiaochu:  f(x) does not equal $e^x$ -- that's why I'm asking about a general rule.  Mostly, I am new to this stuff, and it seems like there is a near endless list of tricks, and I was just wondering if I missed one..

Comment: @Angada: there's no reason to expect a rule for integrals of this kind. The only general rules with wide applicability that I can really think of are $u$-substitution and integration by parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in general. If, say, $f(x)=\ln\,x$, one requires a nonelementary function to represent the integral...

Answer (score 6):

No, but there **is** a rule for integrating $f'(x)\,f'(f(x))$.

Comment: what is rule of it?

Comment: The derivative of $f(f(x))$ is what I wrote.  So, the integral of what I wrote is $f(f(x)) +C$.

Answer (score -5):

I suggest integration by parts where $u=f(x)$ and $dv=f(f(x))dx$

$du=f'(x)dx$ and $v=\int f(f(x))dx$ , this integral we may evaluate as $v=\int f(x)dx \int f(x)dx$